# Timer doesn't stop. Trying to do clicks for n steps

Tags: java, timer, imagej

I want to do a timer that executes the method `mouseRelease` for 15 times every 300 ms. For this purpose I have written something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class myapp extends PlugInFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener, MouseListener {
     [...]
     int total = 0;
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {
            [...]
            if (total == 0){
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();          
            }else if (total==14){
                timer.stop;
                total =0;
            }     
        }

    Timer timer = new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             try {
                if (total < 15){
                    total++;
                    Robot r = new Robot();
                    r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);    
                }
            } catch(AWTException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create java.awt.Robot for Robo instance", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that although it does well its work, at the end it doesn't stop the timer so until I end completely the program it doesn't stop to do clicks. What's wrong with it?

I wish I could print the var total to see if it increases but this code is for a plugin in ImageJ and I don't know how to print and later see the log.

Answer (score 0):

The mouseReleased() code is executed only once, when you release the mouse. It is not executed 15 times. When the Timer is started the ActionListener code takes over and is executed every 300ms.

It is easier to stop the Timer in the ActionListener code itself, since this is where the value of the total variable is incremented.

Maybe something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (total == 15)
    {
        Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();
        timer.stop();
    }
    else
    {
        // invoke your current code
    }
}
```

Must admit I don't really understand your logic so I can't make any better suggestion. That is I don't understand why you are attempting to generate 15 mouseReleased() events in succession.

Edit:

A simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTime extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel timeLabel;
    private int count = 0;

    public TimerTime()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        add( timeLabel );

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);

        if (count == 10)
        {
            Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerTime");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TimerTime() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't stop with your solution. I am tracking an object in a series of images. The code that I have forces you to click every image for every object tracked. I do have to track around 50 objects along 288 pictures. Trust me, I am going to broke my wrist and my mouse. It is a better idea to only move the mouse ;)

Comment: @Learningfrommasters, the concept works fine as the demo from above shows. The problem is your implementation of the suggestion. Maybe the problem is you don't reset the count every time you start the Timer. Anyway the code is posted is not executable so I can't really give specific advice.

Comment: Thank you for your help. At the end, I managed to debug my plugin with Eclipse and I realised that the problem was because of bad .clases and because timer.stop; needed () after stop.