# How to cycle through rainbow color Combination Java

Tags: java, swing, rgb, game-development

I have found some other similar questions but they do not really answer my question.
Currently I'm making a game and I want this object on the screen to cycle through the rainbow colours.

This class has a method called tick and render; each of these is run every game tick. I didnt even bother running the example below as i dont know how to approach this question.

```
Color c;
int r=0,g=0,b=0;
boolean ascending = true;

public void tick(){
    while(ascending) {
            if(r <= 255)
                r++;
            else
                break;
            if(g <= 255)
                g++;
            else
                break;
            if(b <= 255)
                b++;
            else
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want this object on the screen to cycle through the rainbow colours.

1. Create an `ArrayList` of `Color` objects to represent the colors of the rainbow.
2. Create a Swing Timer for the animation.
3. Each timer the Timer fires you get the Color object at index 0 from the ArrayList at set the color of your component.
4. Then remove the Color object at index 0.
5. When the ArrayList is empty, you stop the Timer.

See: [Timer doesn't stop. Trying to do clicks for n steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795610/timer-doesnt-stop-trying-to-do-clicks-for-n-steps/31795969#31795969) for a basic example that updates the time for 10 seconds and then stops.